# logrotate Compress doesn't work at all redhat 7

Tags: logrotate

My logrotate compress is not working at all. Log rotation will rotate file but it doesn't compress at all. Any simple mistake i am doing please let me know. 
This is output of logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.conf

```
rotating pattern: /var/log/btmp  monthly (1 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/btmp
  log does not need rotating

rotating pattern: /tmp/app/stderr  419430400 bytes (1 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /tmp/app/stderr
  log needs rotating
rotating log /tmp/app/stderr, log->rotateCount is 1
dateext suffix '-20160603'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding logs to compress failed
glob finding old rotated logs failed
fscreate context set to unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0
renaming /tmp/app/stderr to /tmp/app/stderr-20160603
creating new /tmp/app/stderr mode = 0755 uid = 0 gid = 0
set default create context
[root@localhost app]# ls -l 
total 2103448
```

---

And here is my conf file logrotate.conf

```
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext
# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
compress

# RPM packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp and btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
        minsize 1M
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0600 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

# system-specific logs may be also be configured here.

/tmp/app/stderr {
     missingok
     rotate 1
     daily
     size 400M
     compress
     su
}
```

Comment: Issue is compress is not working at all in my case.

Comment: I have already attached output of -v which is equivlant to -d option             -d     Turns  on  debug mode and implies -v.  In debug mode, no changes
              will be made to the logs or to the logrotate state file.

Comment: unlikely, but perhaps you dont have gzip installed?

Comment: This is output of "which gzip" command    
/usr/bin/gzip     so that means gzip is installed.

Comment: +1 I see the same thing happening on CentOS7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `delaycompress` to the configuration section for `/var/log/` will solve the problem.

From `man logrotate`:

```
delaycompress

      Postpone  compression of the previous log file to the next rota‐
      tion cycle.  This only has effect when used in combination  with
      compress.   It  can  be used when some program cannot be told to
      close its logfile and thus might continue writing to the  previ‐
      ous log file for some time.
```

Interestingly, the original configuration I had (without the `delaycompress` directive), came straight out of `man logrotate` (except I changed `weekly` to `daily`):

```
# sample logrotate configuration file
compress

/var/log/messages {
     rotate 5
     weekly
     postrotate
         /usr/bin/killall -HUP syslogd
     endscript
 }
```

Comment: Its not solving problem yet

Comment: This answer from rahul appears copy-pasted from an older thread: http://serverfault.com/questions/116201/logrotate-does-not-compress-var-log-messages